# How do I get the date a MongoDB collection was created using MongoDB C# driver?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to iterate through all of the collections in my MongoDB database and get the time when each of the collections was created (I understand that I could get the timestamp of each object in the collection, but I would rather not go that route if a simpler/faster method exists).

This should give you an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
MongoDatabase _database;
// code elided
var result = _database.GetAllCollectionNames().Select(collectionName =>
    {
        _database.GetCollection( collectionName ) //.{GetCreatedDate())
    });
```

Comment: JFYI, Agreed with most answers! You can't find when a collection was created with any MongoDB query! Your best bet will be getting date from `_id` as suggested. But prior to that check:: collection was never dropped & re-created using `$out`, It's not a `capped collection`, no `TTL indexes`, no `Online Archive enabled`. If you can say this:: `Oldest doc was preserved` then you're most likely good!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, MongoDB doesn't keep track of collection creation dates.  However, it's really easy to do this yourself.  Add a simple method, something like this, and use it whenever you create a new collection:

```
public static void CreateCollectionWithMetadata(string collectionName)
{
    var result = _db.CreateCollection(collectionName);
    if (result.Ok)
    {
        var collectionMetadata = _db.GetCollection("collectionMetadata");
        collectionMetadata.Insert(new { Id = collectionName, Created = DateTime.Now });
    }
}
```

Then whenever you need the information just query the `collectionMetadata` collection. Or, if you want to use an extension method like in your example, do something like this:

```
public static DateTime GetCreatedDate(this MongoCollection collection)
{
    var collectionMetadata = _db.GetCollection("collectionMetadata");
    var metadata = collectionMetadata.FindOneById(collection.Name);
    var created = metadata["Created"].AsDateTime;
    return created;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The "creation date" is not part of the collection's metadata. A collection does not "know" when it was created. Some indexes have an `ObjectId()` which implies a timestamp, but this is not consistent and not reliable.

Therefore, I don't believe this can be done.

Comment: can't we get that info from the oplog?

Comment: The oplog cycles over time, so unless you happen to watching at the moment it's created, it's just not there.

Answer (score 2):

Like Mr. Gates VP say, there is no way using the metadata... but you can get the oldest document in the collection and get it from the _id.

Moreover, you can insert an "empty" document in the collection for that purpose without recurring to maintain another collection.

And it's very easy get the oldest document:

`old = db.collection.find({}, {_id}).sort({_id: 1}).limit(1)
 dat = old._id.getTimestamp()`

By default, all collection has an index over `_id` field, making the `find` efficient.

(I using MongoDb 3.6)

Comment: How do I query whether a collection has an _id field, whether it's an ObjectID and whether it's indexed?

Comment: Just use the find function over that collection. Just keep in mind that the result is a cursor. But you can convert it to an array using the toArray function. For example.

resultArray = db.your_collection.find( {_id:  ObjectId("633ddca7ed03bf24a61845ed")} ).toArray()

(I'm using MongoDb 5.0)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it's some necroposting but anyway: I tried to find an answer and got it:

Checked it in Mongo shell, don't know how to use in C#:

```
// db.payload_metadata.find().limit(1)

ObjectId("60379be2bec7a3c17e6b662b").getTimestamp()
ISODate("2021-02-25T12:45:22Z")
```