# How to know the creation date of a database in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, mongodb-.net-driver, spring-data-mongodb

How to know the creation date of a database in MongoDB

for database creation the keyword "use" and it also switches to the databases which is already present and show dbs list the databases .
but for a particular database, how to know the creation date 
Please suggest me..

Answer (score 0):

As per @Chris_Fulstow's answer on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083943/how-do-i-get-the-date-a-mongodb-collection-was-created-using-mongodb-c-sharp-dri):

MongoDB doesn't keep track of collection creation dates. However, it's really easy to do this yourself. Add a simple method, something like this, and use it whenever you create a new collection:

```
public static void CreateCollectionWithMetadata(string collectionName)
{
    var result = _db.CreateCollection(collectionName);
    if (result.Ok)
    {
        var collectionMetadata = _db.GetCollection("collectionMetadata");
        collectionMetadata.Insert(new { Id = collectionName, Created = DateTime.Now });
    }
}
```

Then whenever you need the information just query the collectionMetadata collection. Or, if you want to use an extension method, do something like this:

```
public static DateTime GetCreatedDate(this MongoCollection collection)
{
    var collectionMetadata = _db.GetCollection("collectionMetadata");
    var metadata = collectionMetadata.FindOneById(collection.Name);
    var created = metadata["Created"].AsDateTime;
    return created;
}
```