# Most recently added collection in a Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

Within a Mongo Database, how do i get the most recently added/updated  collection?

```
> show collections;
> collection_1
> collection_2
> collection_3
> ...........
> ...........
> collection_n
n can vary from 1 to 1000;
```

My application adds a new collection or might update an existing collection. How do retreive the last updated or a newly added collection within a database?

Methods that i looked in the internet,applies to within a collection,
for example the answers shown here [Get the latest record from mongodb collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920651/get-the-latest-record-from-mongodb-collection)

Comment: Check the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083943/how-do-i-get-the-date-a-mongodb-collection-was-created-using-mongodb-c-sharp-dri). MongoDB itself does not store any Date info. Therefore, you may want to have the separate collection to keep track of other collections (i.e. when you create a collection, have a method to update "meta" collection, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

there is no built in solution to it, you need implement it.

you can implement this solution diagrammaticall.

Ie.: log last operation timestamp for each collection, you can store in new
collection;

Answer (score 0):

```
Collection's metadata doesn't have any created date. 
So, A collection does not "know" when it was created.
```

In short it can not be possible!

Answer (score 0):

by using updated column date and time you can get the result

```
db.collectionname.find().sort( { UpdatedOn: -1 } )
```